# error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so:

Tags: java-native-interface

I am trying to make this [JNI example](http://giridhar-mb.blogspot.de/2012/11/calling-java-function-from-c.html) works. 
I am able to compile all the files but I can not launch the executable because of this error :

> ./TEST: error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have checked all the paths, the compilation goes without errors...
Now I think that is linked with my operating system (OpenSuse) or my java version : 
I am running java 1.7 and the code use the JVM 1.6 (`vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;`).. and JNI_VERSION_1_7 does not seem to exist.

Comment: Try wrapping the command in a sh script which sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable to include the directory of the correct libjvm.so. That ought to at least work around the problem if it's a simple misconfiguration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a very good example, one of the best on the web I guess, because the author wrote down the paths of each file he uses : [Tutorial](http://tlab.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/01/12/125702)

I still had a library problem so here is how I managed to get all working :

1. Create the java and the cc files (cf. link above) in the same repertory.
2. Edit the following line in main.cc with the path of your Java class :

`{ const_cast<char*>("-Djava.class.path=PATH_TO_JAVA_CLASS"), NULL }`

3. Go the repertory and compile the java class :

`$ javac Main.java`.

4. Look for the file `libjvm.so` on your computer. Once you have
   found it, edit the lib path as follows :

`$ LIBPATH=PATH_TO_LIBJVM.SO`

(for me it was in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/server`
)

5. Export the lib path

`$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${LIBPATH}`

6. Now you just have to compile the main.cc file. I had a problem because `jni.h` was not found:

   a.  Find `jni.h` (for me `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0/include/`)

   b.  If you have a problem with `jni_md.h`, create a symbolic link of  `jni_md.h` in the same folder of `jni.h`

   c.  Compile as follows :

`$ g++ -Wall main.cc -I/PATH_TO_jni.h -L${LIBPATH} -ljvm`

7. Should be good :)

`./a.out`

> Hello, world!
>
> Hello, Java!